# How to convert solid part to shell part in Abaqus?

Tags: finite-element-method, abaqus

I want to compare the same model with solid shape and shell shape,
since my model is big, I am wondering if there is a way to convert the solid part into a shell in Abaqus easily without creating a new model from the beginning?

Please help me resolve this problem
Thank you very much..

Comment: Do you have  any Pictures?